# what does "save all files" mean in vscode? I'm looking to delete all exe files automatically after I get my output in C

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

In VS Code, what happens if I don't save all files under the Code Runner extension settings? What files are they talking about? The exe files? How can I automatically delete all exe files, as it will eventually take up storage.

I am using Code Runner and MakeHidden extensions, but can't find any solutions online for this problem. Also I am a beginner.

Comment: It usually means all the source files that you have edited, but not yet saved.

Comment: The 'clean' option usually deletes the object files, executables, etc. Not sure about your automatic requirement - how would that know how many times you want to run the executable?

Answer (score 1):

Its asking if you want to save all of the files you edited.  Each page you type on in vs code is a different file being stored on your system.  Save all saves changes made on all of them.

Comment: Exactly. As with any editor, “save all” only applies to _the files being edited_. An IDE may _generate_ additional files (such as an `.exe`), but as those are not the files being edited, they are not “saved” in any way. (Nor are they not-saved in any way — the editor does not care about them.)